# GridView with image and text on center

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-imageview

Hi I want develop this type of layout but i am confused that is it the gridview or imageviews aligned like that .
Well my question is how can i acheive this type of menu in my fragment in which i am working

[image]

After Implementing Gridview from https://www.learn2crack.com/2014/01/android-custom-gridview.html

i got this like screen

[image]

how can i make the gridView look like at first image ?

as the text on the center of the block i really want to achieve it .

**grid_single.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/denist_3"
        android:layout_height="50dp">
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_text"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Dentist"
        android:textSize="9sp" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**main_act.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <GridView
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:layout_below="@+id/comsp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:columnWidth="150dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Adapterclass.java**

```
public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context mContext;
    private final String[] web;
    private final int[] Imageid;

    public CustomGrid(Context c,String[] web,int[] Imageid ) {
        mContext = c;
        this.Imageid = Imageid;
        this.web = web;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return web.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {

            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            textView.setText(web[position]);
            imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }

        return grid;
    }
}
```

**Mainactivity.java**

```
     CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(getActivity(), web, imageId);

 grid=(GridView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid);
 grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You Clicked at " +web[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

Comment: Post your `xml` file for your views.

Comment: @Pztar check again i edited the question and provided views

Comment: I posted an answer below for your item view, try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an overlay layout, you can use `FrameLayout` since it's child views will stack on top of each other. In your case, your `item_layout.xml` would look like this

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/myimage"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvOverlayText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/mytext"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: ok the text thing worked , i got the text on the center of image view but all the imageviews are not alligned i think its because of different dimensions of pngs i am using ?

Comment: That's an image issue, not a layout issue. The layout is set to fill the full width/height of the view. If your images look misaligned then their dimensions are probably different. Try it with images with equal dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Your xml file is too complicated. You can achieve this simply by using GridView in your activity/fragment layout. Then you'll need a custom adapter class for your Gridview to inflate another xml file which will contain only one imageview and textview.
You can follow this link to get you started with GridView: https://www.learn2crack.com/2014/01/android-custom-gridview.html

Comment: i edited the layout file and made it easy to check imageviews

Comment: Yup , but your approach to the problem is not correct. As well as it'll be really hard to create the exact screen like the screenshot for every single android device available in the market. The best approach is to use GridView. Please look at the link I've mentioned above. It'll solve your problem.

Comment: ok i used that tutorial and build something , can u now guide me how to achieve the layout of gridview as on first image ?

Answer (score 1):

Hey friends I got the solution of above problem..
Check this solution..

1. GridView  in main_activity.xml

   ```
      <GridView
           android:id="@+id/listRequests"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
           android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
           android:columnWidth="10dp"
           android:background="#e1ecef"
           android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
           android:numColumns="2"
           android:listSelector="#e1ecef"
           android:scrollbars="none"
           android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
           android:verticalSpacing="10dp"/>
   ```

   2. Item.xml in custom Adapter

   ```
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/picture"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="128dp"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:adjustViewBounds="true"
       android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
       android:src="@drawable/plumbing" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/text"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_alignBottom="@id/picture"
       android:layout_alignEnd="@id/picture"
       android:layout_alignStart="@id/picture"
       android:layout_alignTop="@id/picture"
       android:layout_margin="1dp"
       android:background="#55000000"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:text=""
       android:textColor="@android:color/white"
       android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
       android:textStyle="normal" />
   ```

   3. This is the output.

[image]

I hope it will helpful for you...